# Setting ScrollView for my layout

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

In My Layout I want to set scrollview for a ListView and imageView. I tried as shown in below.
But it did not work. If I remove the Scrollview then I can able to scroll the Listview. The Items in the Listview are added through the code by downloading from Internet.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/firstImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dip"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: why you are doing in a scrollview?

Comment: no listview in a scrollview. use a header to your list instead.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a scroll view. In any case nested scrolling is not recommended in Android UI.

Simply use ImageView with ListView and set the weight of Listview to be 1.

Answer (score 0):

listview is scrollable so you do not need to use scrollview